# Solr - how to use copyField to copy empty field

Tags: solr, lucene

managed-schema file (Omitted default settings):

```
<field name="content" type="strings"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="Cytokine"/>
<field name="Cytokine" type="strings" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I get this in schema browser when looking at the Cytokine field:

Sorry, no Term Info available :(

There is data in the content field. It is from a document I uploaded which had the content field. Cytokine is a field that I added in the managed-schema file.

The question:

it doesn't seem like there is data in the Cytokine field. I am not sure why because there is a document that has data for the content field. Is this correct behavior for this schema? I want to be able to copy the data from the field that has data to another field that doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Added a clearer quedtion

Comment: Did you reload your core and reindex after adding the copyField directive? It should have both content and should behave as a regular field in regard to other modules such as terms.

Comment: I hit the reload button in the admin panel after adding the copyField directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MatsLindh, it looks like I actually needed to erase the index (delete it) and reupload the documents. Then it copies.